# Replacing a string that contains a certain word with that word

Tags: r, text, replace

I have a column in my df with many different strings, for instance a string would say crossed at point a, or came in through point a. I want to replace that entire string with just a, how could I go about doing this?

Comment: Can you give some examples of your given input and your desired output?

Comment: You could try `df$col[grepl("a", df$col, useBytes = TRUE)] <- "a"` where `df$col` is the column that contains the strings you want to change

Comment: @AllanCameron That would match any string with an `"a"`, put word boundary charcters around it: `"\\ba\\b"`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas you're right of course. I assumed the OP was using "a" as a stand-in for a phrase rather than being a literal "a", but who knows? I had a feeling that the OP might not have knowledge of regex, so thought a simple byte-match would be easier to start with. But your answer (upvoted) is of course more robust than my comment.

Answer (score 2):

Following a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61601973/replacing-a-string-that-contains-a-certain-word-with-that-word#comment108967722_61601973) to the question by user [Allan Cameron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12500315/allan-cameron), here is a full solution with the suggestion I made.

```
df1 <- data.frame(col = c("crossed at point a", 
                          "doesn't match though it has as", 
                          "came in through point a", 
                          "no"))

df1$col[grepl("\\ba\\b", df1$col)] <- "a"
df1
#                              col
#1                               a
#2  doesn't match though it has as
#3                               a
#4                              no
```

## Edit

Following another [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61601973/replacing-a-string-that-contains-a-certain-word-with-that-word?noredirect=1#comment108968368_61601973) by Allan Cameron I have decided to write a small function to make it easier to replace a string that contains a word by that word.

```
replaceWord <- function(x, word){
  pattern <- paste0("\\b", word, "\\b")
  i <- grep(pattern, x)
  x[i] <- word
  x
}

replaceWord(df1$col, "a")
```

Comment: why do you use "\\ba\\b"

Comment: "\\b" matches a word boundary - either before or after.  So "k\\b" would match _black_ but not _blacker_